# In F1, which tyre to start on if the "fastest time"-tyre is damaged?

Tags: rules, equipment, formula-1

During Q3, if the driver loses a tyre due to a puncture, which tyre would he start with in the race the next day?

Secondly, if the pole sitter tries to improve his lap time in Q3 and while doing so loses the tyre due to a puncture in the final sector, which tyre would the driver start with in the main race?

I am not sure if P10 (former case) and P1 (latter case) drivers would be governed by the same rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drivers who make it through to Q3 start the race on the set of tyres that they used to set their fastest time in Q2.

All other divers have free choice of tyre compound to start the race on.

[Formula 1 - Sporting Regulations - 2021](https://www.fia.com/sites/default/files/2021_formula_1_sporting_regulations_-_iss_2_-_2020-05-27_0.pdf)

> 24.4 m) At each Event where a sprint qualifying session is not scheduled, with the exception of any cars that are required to start the race from the pitlane, at the start of the race each car which qualified for Q3 must be fitted with the tyres with which the driver set his fastest time during Q2.
>
> This will only be necessary for these cars if dry-weather tyres were used
> to set the fastest time in Q2 and if dry-weather tyres are used at the start of the race.
>
> Any such tyres damaged during Q2 will be inspected by the Technical Delegate who will decide, at his absolute discretion, whether any may be replaced and, if so, which tyres they should be replaced with.
>
> A penalty under Article 47.3d) will be imposed on any driver whose car is not fitted with the tyres with which he set his fastest time in Q2 (except if damaged tyres have been replaced with the approval of the Technical Delegate).